# ReactiveCocoa subscribe block not called on viewModel in Swift

Tags: ios, mvvm, swift, reactive-cocoa

I'm building an app using MVVM and ReactiveCocoa to do bindings between the viewModel and the UI, however the view model validation signal subscribe block is not getting called.

My view model is pretty simple and barebones:

```
class ViewModel: RVMViewModel {
    var name: String = "" {
        willSet {
            println("New Value: \(newValue)")
        }
    }

   required init(){
       super.init()
       let signal = self.rac_valuesForKeyPath("name", observer: self)
       signal.subscribeNext {
           println("Subscribe block: \($0)")
       }
   }
}
```

In my view controller, I have the following bindings:

```
//observe ui and programatic changes
RACSignal.merge([self.nameField.racTextSignal(), self.nameField.rac_valuesForKeyPath("text", observer:self)]).subscribeNext({
     (next) -> Void in
     if let text = next as? String {
         self.viewModel.name = text
     }
})
RAC(self.nameField, "text") = self.viewModel.rac_valuesForKeyPath("name", observer: self)
```

I got the RAC macro working in swift based off what I read [here](http://napora.org/a-swift-reaction/).

Now, in my view bindings in my view controller, the subscribeNext blocks are called just fine. In my viewModel, in willSet, the new value prints out. HOWEVER, the subscribe block on my signal in my init block is only being called once, when the property is first initialized. This is driving me up a wall, anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution after a bunch of experimenting. By assigning a signal directly to the view model property, the subscribe block is called every time the value changes.

So instead of doing this:

```
RACSignal.merge([self.nameField.racTextSignal(), self.nameField.rac_valuesForKeyPath("text", observer:self)]).subscribeNext({
     (next) -> Void in
     if let text = next as? String {
         self.viewModel.name = text
     }    
})
```

I did this:

```
RAC(self.viewModel, "name") <~  RACSignal.merge([self.nameField.racTextSignal(),     
self.nameField.rac_valuesForKeyPath("text", observer:self)])
```

I used [this link](http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2014/07/24/mvvm-reactivecocoa-swift.html) to get the `RAC` and `<~` to work in swift.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have a solution yet - I am away from my laptop till evening. However, try making signal in the global scope or an instance variable... If that doesn't work, try it on a singleton as a method you explicitly call ... These are more tests but if you tell me how it goes we can work it out together.

Comment: I ended up figuring it out so no worries.

Comment: @startupthekid if you solved it please post the solution, this is SO after all and we like to share what we learn here:)

Answer (score 0):

A better solution than the one that's accepted is to simply mark the property dynamic:

```
dynamic var name: String = "" {
    willSet {
        println("New Value: \(newValue)")
    }
}
```

This enables Obj-C level KVO which is typically disabled for Swift only properties.